# Robocopy script skipping files

Tags: robocopy

I have a robocopy script that's skipping all files even though I'm specifically telling it to move PDF and CSV files and directories recursively. Directories are being created. Can someone help me solve this and I don't get why this is happening.

```
robocopy "\\servername\quote_docs" "\\domain\share" *.pdf *.csv /e /move /MAXAGE:1 /r:3 /log+:C:\robocopyERS\robolog.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `"/MAXAGE:1"` parameter and it should work. That parameter will make Robocopy only consider moving files newer than 1 day.

Comment: Of course! I'm such an idiot. The test files our software provider have generated have a date of 2015!